# Button click events and restart problems

Tags: c#

I have been able to get my exit button to work, but none of the others.  I tried coding the other buttons the same way, but I get an error.  The program also keeps restarting, even after I removed that code.  Can someone tell me where I am going wrong on the other buttons and the restart problem?

```
namespace Module10Project
{
    public partial class frmRadioStar : Form
    {
        public frmRadioStar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBx1.Text = "";
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBx2.Text = "";
        }

        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void rdoAdd_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                Application.Reset();
            }
        }



        private void rdoSub_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btnReset_Click not working?

Comment: *but I get an error*. That is funny. I also get an error here in my own program. All jokes aside. Please share what the error actual is: [edit] your question and copy/paste the error. See [mcve].